# Аналог TextArea JavaFX с разными цветами текста

Tags: java, javafx, color, textarea

Мне нужен аналог TextArea, но только со сменой цвета отдельных букв.
Также нужно, чтобы в нем можно было менять текст. И чтобы не было ничего лишнего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека RichTextFX

Скачать source можно вот тут:
https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX